# Difference b/w dates in weeks, months and years

Tags: sql-server

I have a table for loan installment dates, I want to get the total duration of loan.
The due date for each loan saves in db and it saves on the basis of monthly and weekly. I'm not saving any check to identify the nature of loan either it was monthly or weekly.
Now if the duration between dates in in weeks then it should give the duration in weeks like 27 weeks or 2 weeks and if the duration is in months it should give like 5 months or 2 years and 4 months.

```
LoanID   DueDate     AmountToBePaid
2        2019-01-01  500
2        2019-01-07  500
2        2019-01-14  500
2        2019-01-21  500
2        2019-01-28  500
```

The duration I want is 5 weeks but it is returning 2 months.
There is a master table as well where total installments of loan are being saved. Here is my query, I hope someone can help.

```
SELECT LoanID,
    CASE WHEN NoOfInstallment>12
          THEN CAST(NoOfInstallment/12 AS VARCHAR(10))+' Years '
       ELSE '' END
    +
    CASE WHEN NoOfInstallment%12>0
          THEN CAST(NoOfInstallment%12 AS VARCHAR(10))+' Months'
       ELSE '' END AS [TotalDuration]
FROM LoanMaster
INNER JOIN LoanDetail ON LoanMaster.ID = LoanDetail.LoanID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
SELECT 
  LoanId,
  DATEDIFF(WEEK, inst_start, inst_end) weeks 
FROM LoanMaster LM
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
    select 
      dateadd(month, -1,min(due_date)) inst_start, 
      max(due_date) inst_end
  FROM LoanDetail
) LD
ON LM.ID = LD.LoanID
```